# QString() vs sprintf()

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have some code where in, there is a TCP connection between the client and the server. I need to send some xml data to the server and receive a response from it. I am trying to do it like this:

```
char request[MAX];
sprintf(request, "<attestationRequest><majorVersion>%d</majorVersion><minorVersion>%d</minorVersion></attestationRequest>", major, minor);
write(sockfd,request, length);

while(recv(sockfd, response, MAX, 0) >= 0)
{
    cout << "response " << response;
    //do something;
}
```

But the data received is (expected response + request).

If I try to fill the data using `QString`, the data received is proper.

```
QString request = QString("<attestationRequest>"
                               "<majorVersion>%1</majorVersion>"
                               "<minorVersion>%2</minorVersion>"
                           "</attestationRequest>")
                            .arg(major)
                            .arg(minor)
```

The rest of the code is same for both the cases. I receive more than 11000 bytes of data when I use `sprintf`, but 9000 bytes in case of `QString`. I am not able to understand if I am missing something.

Comment: Use `snprintf` over `sprint`. That way you make sure that you don't overflow the buffer. Also store the return value to know the length of string to send, and to see if `snprintf` truncated it.

Comment: I have used `sprintf` here because I knew the size of the request and I have even allotted more than what it needs.

Comment: @Shwrtha You should still always use `snprintf`. Anyway, code you have here is not enough to determine the problem. What is `MAX`, `major` and `minor`? Why are you using `MAX` to give the request length?

Comment: MAX is 1000, major = 1 and minor = 1

Comment: It's an apples to oranges comparison.  QString is UTF-16 on all platforms, char* can represent any 8-byte encoding.  Either way it's a little hard to know what to make from your sample code because it's missing a rather crucial end quote.

Answer (score 2):

IMO both solution are bad.
It is safer and better to use [QXmlStreamWriter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html#details). Manual manipulation on text will in most cases end with incorrect encoding or missing escape sequence or other xml format violation.

Other problem is that you didn't gave any data how you perform communication. It is highly probable that there is an error causing your problem.

Comment: I use standard `connect()` API for both the cases. There is no error in the connection as such. I am trying to avoid `Qt` dependency. So, I tried to use `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is, that UTF-16 data is sent through the connection (that is QString.)

Maybe if you tried the w_char-versions of those commands, it might succeed.